# How To Sample From 'One' Mipmap Texture Without Artifacts?

Tags: c++, graphics, textures, texture-mapping, mipmaps

In game developing , a common method to reduce texture IO cost is that connect mutiple mipmap-texture images to one image like below.

[image: One MipMapping Image]

However in opengl texture sampling would execute a bilinear interpolation, which cause artifacts in mipmap-texture edges.How to avoid the artifacts?

Maybe sampling from nearst texture uv and software-bilinear interpolation is a valid method but need extra cost.

Comment: You could try using either the nearest filter or using texelfetch in the shader.

Comment: texelfetch could fetch with accuracy uv and lod but in my case , all lod texture would be stored in one texture image and sometimes bilinear interpolation is neccesary for shading.

Comment: Yes, but with texelfetch you can determine if a pixel lies close to the border, if it does you use texelfetch to retrieve the pixel and its neighbours then interpolate yourself, otherwise yo sample normally and let the filter do its thing.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you say

> a common method to reduce texture IO cost is that connect mutiple mipmap-texture images to one image like below.

and I was thinking perhaps you meant as in a [texture atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas) but then your example appears to show only a single image with 2 copies of the MIP map level 1, 4 (!) copies of MIP map level 2, and 2^N copies of level N!

What texture I/O cost are you aiming to save? As far as I can see (and I've been involved in the development of graphics hardware for some years) this makes matters worse. I wondered if this was possibly for some kind of software renderer but then you mention OpenGL so this seems unlikely.

Why don't you just stick with the traditional approach? Pass in the top level map to the API and then, either, manually supply the lower resolution maps *or*, if available, let the hardware generate them for you?

Graphics hardware (at least all I've been involved with) is highly optimised - in terms of use of memory bandwidth and execution rate - to handle this scenario efficiently, and the issues with borders that you are concerned with will go away.

BTW, for this sort of question, you could also try the https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/ community.